Corrupted vector values with Nomic embedding models in LM Studio on Mac
I am using Nomic embedding models in LM Studio. It works but the vectors it returns are systematically corrupted : every time there is a line in the middle of the vectors values as follows :
...
 0.04597519710659981,
        -0.010298278
100 23435  100 23346  100    89   405k   1584 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  408k
18274498,
        0.012535640969872475,
...

And therefore I get an error when parsing the json.
I have tried with 2 different models :
text-embedding-nomic-embed-text-v1
text-embedding-nomic-embed-text-v1.5

I am on a Mac Mini Pro 24Gb with OS 15.1.1
What am I doing wrong ?
